# REST API best practice on handling errors

Tags: rest, exception, design-patterns, error-handling

I'm wondering how should errors be handled on a REST API backend, internally. Say the user gives an incomplete request payload, fails validation, or looking for something that does not exist. We'll want to return 400 or 404 for those cases.

In some frameworks (only those that I have experience with), we do this by throwing exceptions (NestJS, Spring, etc). But on Go, there's the `error` returned by operation methods (validation, access to db) that can indicate the error (`if err != nil`) and we can *bubble-up* the `err` up to the controller level and have different handling for it (return some specific status, error message, etc).

My question is, which way (or if there's another preferred way) is the best to handle errors on a backend? The problem is throwing exceptions will show on any logs monitoring tools and will show that the app have so many errors even though most might be 4XX errors (we could filter the logs to find 50X errors definitely), and using the `errors` return object might be cumbersome to *bubble-up* for every validation functions we'd have. I'll be happy if there's any repository example or article that explains the similar topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see with throwing exceptions is that we may give out some internal error to the users, which may not benefit them and will also expose our implementation.

> using the errors return object might be cumbersome to bubble-up for every validation functions we'd have.

Yes propagating the error can be cumbersome, but I think that it is good to propagate required errors from the called function to the callee and let the callee decide what they want to do. For the rest call, I think it is ok if we propagate the error from the DB layer to the service layer to the rest layer.

Also, we can wrap the error at the rest layer into a standard response message

```
{
    "type": "/errors/incorrect-user-pass",
    "title": "Incorrect username or password.",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Authentication failed due to incorrect username or password.",
    "instance": "/login/log/abc123"
}
```

We can do this by calling a wrapper function for handling error when we call `Http.Handle()`. This [post](https://medium.com/@ozdemir.zynl/rest-api-error-handling-in-go-behavioral-type-assertion-509d93636afd) contains example function `ServeHTTP()`.

**Credit**: The `serveHTTP` function was taken from [Zeynel Özdemir](https://medium.com/@ozdemir.zynl) and the response object example from `https://www.baeldung.com/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! I agree with your points especially formatting the error response message. But from my view, with propagating error objects through different layers, it adds more code (to check) and resulted in detailed and verbose code. For Go and other languages that can return multiple values (`return result, err`) it'll be better, but for language like Java and TS, we'll need a generic wrapper, and everything will be using the wrapper, even more code (`Promise<ResponseWrapper<User>>`).

Comment: I'm thinking about a third way, namely throwing exceptions but catch it on controller (or similar, refer to NestJS' exception filter below) level, handles 4XX or 5XX errors, translate and wrap it to a common error format (as your example), and return the response.

I'm using NestJS and it have [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) that I can utilize for this. What do you think about that approach? Are there any similar patterns?

Comment: I also like the third way of handling it at the controller level, I have implemented a similar one in java using https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring. But I could not find something similar in go.